# Do Squeaky Pufts provide a net increase of bleach stone and chlorine?

Tags: oxygen-not-included

[Squeaky Pufts](https://oxygennotincluded.gamepedia.com/Puft#Squeaky_Puft) consume [Chlorine](https://oxygennotincluded.gamepedia.com/Chlorine) and produce [Bleach Stone](https://oxygennotincluded.gamepedia.com/Bleach_Stone), which in the game will turn back into chlorine as it evaporates.  Meaning that you can essentially feed the Squeaky Pufts with their own excrement, which is kind of convenient.

[image: Squeaky Pufts]

What I don't know is whether this creates a net surplus or loss of chlorine/bleach stone.  Perhaps it is chlorine neutral even.  But if it is a net positive then its essentially a means to produce chlorine.

Can Squeaky Pufts provide a net increase of bleach stone and chlorine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [answers on the Oxygen not included forum](https://forums.kleientertainment.com/forums/topic/95180-do-squeaky-pufts-provide-an-overall-net-increase-of-bleach-stone-and-chlorine/):

> If I'm not mistaken, they have the typical 50% conversion rate of food
>   (chlorine gas) to excrement (bleachstone).

It appears the Squeaky Pufts convert half the mass of gas into solid bleach stone and the puft consumes the other half of the mass.  I assume that bleach stone converts back into an equal mass of chlorine through evaporation.